# MS Excel - Epplus- RGB values not read for Theme colors

Tags: c#, excel

[image]I am trying to read the argb value of a cell using epplus 4.5.2. I am able to read the same for most of the cells. For two particular colors in my file epplus is returning null as values. I did further digging into stack trace and found that pattern type for these cells with two colors are null.

COLOR RGB values found out using Excel Color picker tool are :

COLOR 1 : R = 198, G = 224, B = 180 (Theme Color)
COLOR 2 : R = 172, G = 185, B = 202 (Theme Color)
COLOR 3 : R = 201, G = 201, B = 201 (Theme Color) Pattern type Solid set for this.

I have tried changing the colors of these cells to solid red and epplus seems to recognizing the red color for those same cells.

Answer (score 0):

The theme color field is set for all colors which are not providing rgb values. I will have to write a method for converting theme value and tint value to RGB values.